# Vietnamese font

Tags: windows, fonts, stata, display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwHJr.png)
I have opened a .dta file in stata, the data is written in Vietnamese language. However, it only displays "?" signs. Is there any way to fix this error? Thank you very much

I have tried a few ways but none of the results are correct.